# Can Donald Trump's Tax Returns be obtained through a Freedom of Information Request?

Tags: foia

The IRS, which is part Federal Government clearly has copies of Donald Trump's Tax Returns. Can these be obtained through a Freedom of Information request, given the public's legitimate interest in the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nor can I request a copy of your tax return. See [5 USC 552a](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/552a). Record maintained on an individual are not subject to disclosure.